# AngularJS: How to addClass/removeClass with passed in id as $scope variable?

Tags: angularjs, scope, removeclass

Earlier in my code, I pass an element ID into my code and set a variable to it. Afterwards, I try to `removeClass()` from the element with that ID.

```
//$scope.myID is equal to some id string like 'element123'

$scope.clearClass = function () {
    var target = angular.element(document.querySelector($scope.myID));
    target.removeClass('clicked');
}
```

I don't believe that the right variable is being found here, or passed in the `querySelector` correctly.

The documentation says the way it should be is: `querySelector('#element123')` but I don't know how to do that with a passed in variable like $scope.myID.

How would I do this so that if there were multiple elements, say for example buttons, that if one were clicked addClass would only apply to that button, and removeClass would apply to the rest of the buttons?

Comment: I would go for <element ng-class="{{myID === 'element123' ? 'clicked' : ''}}"></element>

Comment: @Damiano the purpose I'm trying to achieve is saving the id of a previously clicked element, and wiping the class when another element is clicked, so that there's always only one element on the page with said class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't manipulate DOM in controller. Use [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) directive:

```javascript
$scope.clearClass = function () {
    $scope.clickedFlag = false;
}
```

and in HTML

```html
<div ng-class="{ clicked: clickedFlag }"></div>
```

Comment: will give you answer if you add an edit, how to add class clicked on current element, remove class clicked from all other elements. If the `clearClass` function is actually the `ng-click` of that element? I'm just confused on how that would work..

Comment: @VolcovMeter Use [ngFocus](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngFocus) to detect clicking on the element (`ng-focus="clickedFlag = true"`) and [ngBlur](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBlur) when the it focused out (`ng-blur="clickedFlag = false"`) - Add those to the **input** element

Comment: @AlonEitan can you please post as an answer? I am trying your suggestion, but sadly all elements become added with class 'clicked' with your code.

Comment: @VolcovMeter I have to go, but if the elements are inside `ng-repeat` change all the references from `clickedFlag` to `clickedFlag[$index]`, or give each input a different flag for example: `clickedFlagName`, `clickedFlagEmail` and so on...

Comment: @AlonEitan One more question before you go, when trying this, should I include `ng-class="{ clicked: clickedFlag }"` ?

Comment: @VolcovMeter Yes, but with the same reference _Clicked flag_ as its input `ng-class="{ clicked: clickedFlag[$index] }"`Or `ng-class="{ clicked: clickedFlagName }"`, `ng-class="{ clicked: clickedFlagEmail }"`

Comment: @AlonEitan I noticed something, if clicking on any non-element on the page, focus gets turned off on the element ( if I select an input, but click on the background, it removes focus off that element), is there any way to keep focus on the element even if outer page is clicked/engaged?

Comment: @VolcovMeter Please post a new question with the updated details and the issue you're having. I'll try to answer there

Comment: @AlonEitan http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38572417/angularjs-how-to-not-lose-focus-on-element-if-other-elements-are-clicked-using