# AngularJS: How to not lose focus on element if other elements are clicked (using ng-focus/ng-blur)?

Tags: angularjs, focus, ng-class

I've got some elements inside an `ng-repeat` loop that have these attributes:

```
<div ng-repeat="h in myObjectArray">
    <div>
        <input ng-class="{ clicked: clickedFlag1 }" ng-focus="clickedFlag1 = true" ng-blur="clickedFlag1 = false" type="button" id="1" value="1" ng-click="btnSelected(1)" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input ng-class="{ clicked: clickedFlag2 }" ng-focus="clickedFlag2 = true" ng-blur="clickedFlag2 = false" type="button" id="2" value="2" ng-click="btnSelected(2)" />
    </div>
</div>
```

What happens is when one of the elements is clicked, it add class `clicked` to the clicked element, and removes the `clicked` class from all other button inputs.

The problem is, if I click on any other element on the rest of the page, the element I previously clicked no longer has focus and gets it's `clicked` class removed.

Is there anyway to still use `ng-focus` and `ng-blur` like I am using above but have the element that's clicked to have `clicked` class even when other elements on the page are clicked?

To explain: Previously before going about this solution, I was locating elements via `querySelector`, adding and removing classes that way. Someone pointed out that using DOM through AngularJS this way wasn't efficient, so I went with this way.

The problem initially was to select one button and ONLY that button to hold a `clicked` class.

Now the problem is for that element to hold that clicked class if anything else is selected on the page.

Comment: can u provide plunker

Comment: Not sure I understand - Can you please explain what exactly you're trying to do? Just the requirements, without the current problems

Comment: @AlonEitan Yes, once an option is selected out of these inputs, the class `clicked` is added to the input button, but if any other element on the page is clicked thereafter (even the background), the element which was previously clicked loses focus and loses the class `clicked`. Is there anyway to still have the `clicked` class active on the button after other elements on the page are clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now when I know what you're trying to do, this is my suggestion

```
<div ng-repeat="h in myObjectArray">
    <div>
        <input ng-class="{ clicked: clickedFlag1 == $index }" ng-click="btnSelected(1, $index)" type="button" ng-attr-id="btn1_{{ $index }}" value="1" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input ng-class="{ clicked: clickedFlag2 == $index }" ng-click="btnSelected(2, $index)" type="button" ng-attr-id="btn2_{{ $index }}" value="2" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, on your controller, change the `btnSelected` function and allow it to accept the second parameter:

```
$scope.btnSelected = function(btnNumber, btnIndex) {
    if( btnNumber == 1 ) {
        $scope.clickedFlag1  = btnIndex;
    } else {
        $scope.clickedFlag2  = btnIndex;
    }
    // .... rest of your code
}
```

Note that `btnNumber` is a made up name, replace it with the current parameter name you're using in your function.

When you're inside `ngRepeat` you have `$index` that reference to the current index in the loop, so when you click on the button, you set `clickFlag1 = $index` when you click on the first button (from within the controller) on every button groups OR `clickFlag2 = $index` for the second button.

This will allow the `ngClass` to set the `click` class on the button based on the current index, instead of trusting the focus/blur.

FYI - Having multiple elements with the same `id` is a bad practice (you're inside `ngRepeat`), you can change the current `id` to `ng-attr-id="btn1_{{ $index }}"` for the first button on each group, and `ng-attr-id="btn2_{{ $index }}"` for the second button. Don't forget to remove the current `id` attributes.